# Neo4j seraph-model: Create a node with relation to other node

Tags: node.js, neo4j

Hi i have started working the neo4j and the `seraph` and `seraph-model` packages.

A problem poped: 
I cannot seem to find an way to create a Node connected to other node in one query example:

`Create (n:User)-[r:Has]->(p:UserImage)`
I know I can do that using a the native `seraph.query` but then I lose some of the model features.. (like the timestamps)

Is there some otherway to do that?
How expensive is to do that query in 3 steps? (create user, create image, link then)

Comment: Your sample Cypher query *can* create 2 nodes and a relationship at the same time. Can you explain in more detail what the problem is?

Comment: @cybersam  this is more a seraph-model problem i know that i can create two nodes in one query but the question is how i do that with seraph without losing the model features

Comment: Seraph is quite well documented, if you don't find, it please raise a docs issue on their github repository.

Answer (score 1):

seraph-model is extension of seraph. seraph.query is for raw query. model features are accessible only when use modelName.Method